# Run Sidekiq as daemon on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, daemon, sidekiq

How can I run sidekiq as daemon on Ubuntu?

If I run `bundle exec sidekiq -D` I get `invalid option: -D`, is there any way to run it without some other controller, like god, upstart...?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

there's an option to Daemonize sidekiq, just pass `-d` option

[commit](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/commit/7f9d4a39603d2c2cb618104e89e8aab523a48ad9)

Comment: There's an upstart script in examples/upstart that you should use.  Using upstart you'll get respawning and it'll start when you boot - two very useful properties.

Comment: Using `-d` will need to specify a log file with `-L` option. Just sharing because I encountered an error when I tried to use it daemonized.

Comment: @axil Thanks for noting it. As a further data point, I found you don't need the `-L` arg as long as you have a `logfile` declared inside `sidekiq.yml`.

Comment: Doesn't seems to be working for jruby: `ObjectSpace is disabled; each_object will only work with Class, pass -X+O to enable`

Comment: @mahemoff I don't have sidekiq.yml

Comment: Hey and how to stop demonizing?

Answer (score 8):

As of sidekiq 6.0 Daemonization wouldnt work and if you pass -d, you'll get a message:

> Daemonization mode was removed in Sidekiq 6.0, please use a proper process supervisor to start and manage your services

check the issue here [#4045](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/4045)

Answer (score 6):

Running as daemon won't restart the `sidekiq` if it crashes unexpectedly. One alternate way could be to run sidekiq as a service (An upstart job). If the system is rebooted than also the upstart job will run sidekiq.
[**Here**](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/02/sidekiq-upstart-job-or-sidekiq-as.html) is the complete script and method to run sidekiq as a service.

After running sidekiq as a service you can simply `start/stop/restart` sidekiq by command `sudo service sidekiq start/stop/restart`.

Answer (score 1):

Daemonization, running a program as Unix, for Sidekiq version 6 or later is not supported. Instead, we have to run the process as a service.

Write a script according to your bundler location, or you can modify the below code snippet and copy the snippet into `/usr/lib/systemd/system` (CentOS) or `/lib/systemd/system` (Ubuntu)

```
[Unit]
Description=sidekiq

After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]

Type=notify
WatchdogSec=10
WorkingDirectory=/home/deploy/apps/project_name

# If you use rbenv:
# ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'exec /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec sidekiq -e production'
# If you use the system's ruby:
# ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/bundle exec sidekiq -e production
# If you use rvm in production, don't.

#ExecStart=/home/deploy/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.6.5/bundle exec sidekiq -e production

# Use `systemctl kill -s TSTP sidekiq` to quiet the Sidekiq process
# !!! Change this to your deploy user account !!!

User=deploy

Environment=MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2

# if the script crash, restart
RestartSec=1
Restart=on-failure

# output goes to /var/log/syslog (Ubuntu) or /var/log/messages (CentOS)
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog

# This will default to "bundler" if we don't specify it
SyslogIdentifier=sidekiq
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Make sure you have given the correct path of your bundler for `ExecStart` in order to start the process. Save it as `sidekiq.service` and run `systemctl enable sidekiq`. Then we can manage the process using the commands `systemctl start sidekiq`, `systemctl stop sidekiq`, and `systemctl restart sidekiq`.

We can see the last 100 lines of log by using `journalctl -u sidekiq -rn 100`.