# RAILS: Unable to install daemon plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, daemon

Daemon Plugin:
https://github.com/dougal/daemon_generator

When I do

```
rails plugin install git://github.com/dougal/daemon_generator.git
```

I get this output:

```
Usage:
  rails plugin new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                         # Default: /home/nicki/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/ruby
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to some plugin template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]              # Don't create a Gemfile
  -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                      # Skip .gitignore file
      [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                  # Skip source control .keep files
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]          # Skip Sprockets files
      [--skip-spring], [--no-skip-spring]                # Don't install Spring application preloader
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                              # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                         # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]                          # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                                         # Default: jquery
  -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--dev], [--no-dev]                                # Setup the plugin with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge], [--no-edge]                              # Setup the plugin with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
      [--skip-turbolinks], [--no-skip-turbolinks]        # Skip turbolinks gem
  -T, [--skip-test-unit], [--no-skip-test-unit]          # Skip Test::Unit files
      [--rc=RC]                                          # Path to file containing extra configuration options for rails command
      [--no-rc], [--no-no-rc]                            # Skip loading of extra configuration options from .railsrc file
      [--dummy-path=DUMMY_PATH]                          # Create dummy application at given path
                                                         # Default: test/dummy
      [--full], [--no-full]                              # Generate a rails engine with bundled Rails application for testing
      [--mountable], [--no-mountable]                    # Generate mountable isolated application
      [--skip-gemspec], [--no-skip-gemspec]              # Skip gemspec file
      [--skip-gemfile-entry], [--no-skip-gemfile-entry]  # If creating plugin in application's directory skip adding entry to Gemfile

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]                    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]      # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip], [--no-skip]        # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help], [--no-help]  # Show this help message and quit

Description:
    The 'rails plugin new' command creates a skeleton for developing any
    kind of Rails extension with ability to run tests using dummy Rails
    application.

Example:
    rails plugin new ~/Code/Ruby/blog

    This generates a skeletal Rails plugin in ~/Code/Ruby/blog.
    See the README in the newly created plugin to get going.
```

I have no idea why this is happening, I tried doing this inside the rails app and as well as outside but no luck! Still the same.
I am using rails 4.2.3

I also tried doing:

```
rails plugin new install git://github.com/dougal/daemon_generator.git
```

It created some files.
create

```
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  install.gemspec
      create  MIT-LICENSE
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  lib/install.rb
      create  lib/tasks/install_tasks.rake
      create  lib/install/version.rb
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  test/install_test.rb
      append  Rakefile
  vendor_app  test/dummy
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies........
Using rake 10.4.2
Installing i18n 0.7.0
Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions
Installing minitest 5.8.1
Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
Installing activesupport 4.2.4
Installing builder 3.2.2
Installing erubis 2.7.0
Installing mini_portile 0.6.2
Installing nokogiri 1.6.6.2 with native extensions
Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
Installing loofah 2.0.3
Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
Installing actionview 4.2.4
Installing rack 1.6.4
Installing rack-test 0.6.3
Installing actionpack 4.2.4
Installing globalid 0.3.6
Installing activejob 4.2.4
Installing mime-types 2.6.2
Installing mail 2.6.3
Installing actionmailer 4.2.4
Installing activemodel 4.2.4
Installing arel 6.0.3
Installing activerecord 4.2.4
Using bundler 1.10.6
Installing thor 0.19.1
Installing railties 4.2.4
Installing sprockets 3.4.0
Installing sprockets-rails 2.3.3
Installing rails 4.2.4
Using install 0.0.1 from source at .
Installing sqlite3 1.3.10 with native extensions
Bundle complete! 2 Gemfile dependencies, 35 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
```

Then I tested using this command

```
rails generate daemon test
```

And I got this error:

```
Could not find generator 'daemon'. Maybe you meant 'job', 'mailer' or 'task'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options.
```

I am unable to install daemon for rails.

And when I do:

```
./script/generate daemon testdaemon
```

I get this error:

```
zsh: no such file or directory: ./script/generate
```

Even though I have the script folder.

Comment: the last commit was > 5 years ago and the issues show it not working for rails 3.x very well, most say they just install the gem, and then use it directly,

Comment: I have put the gem in the gemfile.. not sure what is wrong, I also did manual install sudo gem install daemons and still no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins do not exist for rails any more. Anything written for Rails 2 (or 3) are unlikely to work with 4 or the upcoming version 5.

You could try checking the code into lib/ and require the files from within config/application.

Comment: hey could you tell me the difference between daemon and sidekiq, if I am using sidekiq, do I need to install daemons ?

Comment: just use sidekiq, see all the comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520676/run-sidekiq-as-daemon-on-ubuntu or many other related questions!